# How to swap an H1 element from an H1 in another document using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please bear with me because I'm student. My instructor had us watch 5 YouTube videos and now expects us to program using JQuery instead of standard JavaScript. All I want to do is swap an  element with an  element from another file.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Testing JQuery</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="header">Testing JQuery</h1>
    <p id ="dummy">Lorem Ipsum </p>
    <script src="changes.js"></script>
    <form name="input" action="changes.js">
    <input type="button" value="Change the Header">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my JavaScript/JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('form');
    $('#header').load( greeting.html + '#ajax h1');
    return false;
  });
});
```

The third file is called greeting.html and this is all it contains:

```
<h1 id="ajax">Hello from jQuery with AJAX</h1>
```

Comment: Can you describe the problem you're having?

Comment: did you try to run this? because `$('#header').load( greeting.html + '#ajax h1');` is illegal syntax.

Comment: @KevinB - Yes I noticed, I'm drunk and confused, sorry.

Comment: just remove the `+` and `h1` from that function and it should work fine. You need quotes around it all though, currently you have no quotes around the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#header').load( 'greeting.html #ajax' );
```

That's all you need. Get rid of all the other stuff.
You dont need to declare `url` and you dont need to return false.

Comment: he wants to do it by clicking an input as he is calling the script if you notice the action declaration within the form element

Comment: Thanks Andreas! That worked perfectly! I knew it was a syntax error on my part, but I couldn't find it!

Answer (score 1):

To replace the element, `load()` won't work as it loads the new H1 inside the old H1, it does not replace it, so you have to use `$.get` and do it yourself :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').on('click', function() {
        $.get({
             url : 'greeting.html'
        }).done(function(data) {
             var h1 = $('<div />').append(data).find('h1#ajax');
             $('#header').replaceWith(h1);
        });
       return false;
    });
});
```